# Saving Iterations in Different CSV Files

Tags: python, csv

For a current project, I am planning to run several iterations of the script below and to save the results in different CSV files with a new file for each iteration (the CSV part is at the end of the script).

The given code currently shows the relevant results in the terminal while it only creates empty CSV files. I have spent days figuring out how to solve the situation but cannot get to a solution. Is there anyone who can help?

Note: I have updated the code in accordance with user recommendations while the original issue/challenge still persists.

```
import string
import json
import csv

import pandas as pd
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Loading and reading dataset
file = open("Glassdoor_A.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])


# Allocate periods for individual CSV file names
periods = pd.period_range('2009Q1','2018Q4',freq='Q')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(40), periods)
type(ts.index)
intervals = ts.index


# Create individual empty files with headers
for i in intervals:
    name = 'Glassdoor_A_' + 'Text Main_' + str(i)
    with open(name+'.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)


        # Create an empty dictionary
        d = dict()


        # Filtering by date
        start_date = pd.to_datetime('2009-01-01')
        end_date = pd.to_datetime('2009-03-31')
        last_end_date = pd.to_datetime('2017-12-31')
        mnthBeg = pd.offsets.MonthBegin(3)
        mnthEnd = pd.offsets.MonthEnd(3)
        while end_date <= last_end_date:
            filtered_dates = df[df.Date.between(start_date, end_date)]
            n = len(filtered_dates.index)
            print(f'Date range: {start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")} - {end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")},  {n} rows.')
            if n > 0:
                print(filtered_dates)
            start_date += mnthBeg
            end_date += mnthEnd


            # Processing Text Main section
            for index, row in filtered_dates.iterrows():
                line = row['Text Main']

                # Remove the leading spaces and newline character
                line = line.split(' ')
                line = [val.strip() for val in line]

                # Convert the characters in line to
                # lowercase to avoid case mismatch
                line = [val.lower() for val in line]

                # Remove the punctuation marks from the line
                line = [val.translate(val.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)) for val in line]
                print(line)
                # Split the line into words
                # words = [val.split(" ") for val in line]
                # print(words)
                # Iterate over each word in line
                for word in line:
                    # Check if the word is already in dictionary
                    if word in d.keys():
                        # Increment count of word by 1
                        d[word] = d[word] + 1
                    else:
                        # Add the word to dictionary with count 1
                        d[word] = 1

                        print(d)


        # Print the contents of dictionary
        for key in list(d.keys()):
            print(key, ":", d[key])

            # Count the total number of words
            total = sum(d.values())
            percent = d[key] / total

            print(d[key], total, percent)


            # Save as CSV file
            while end_date <= last_end_date:

                for index, row in filtered_dates.iterrows():

                    for i in data:
                        name = 'Glassdoor_A_' + str(i)
                        with open(name+'.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
                            writer.writerow(["Word", "Occurrences", "Percentage"])
                            writer.writerows([key, d[key], percent] for key in list(d.keys()))
```

Comment: You should rather not name both your input and output files as `file`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have amended that... it does not move the needle in terms of output shown unfortunately

Comment: _"The files are however either showing as empty lists or a not created at all"_ - it really should be one or the other. Try deleting the previous outfiles and re-run your script to see what it's creating.

Comment: Thanks - just to clarify: the outcome is dependent on the indentation of the CSV part within the script...

Comment: That was going to be my next question - is the indentation of the `# Create individual file names` loop part as per your script or is there an indentation mismatch between your script and the paste above?

Comment: just as a side note: maybe you find https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter useful. Especially the "hamlet" example given in the example might be of interest as it demonstrate how to count words in a text very efficiently.

Answer (score 5):

Wrt your inner loop which writes the CSV files:

```
# Create individual file names
for i in data:
    name = 'Glassdoor_A_' + str(i)

    # Save output in CSV file
    with open(name+'.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        ...
```

⬆ is executed for each iteration of the outer loop `for index, row in filtered_dates.iterrows():`. So each iteration while overwrite the previously created files. Try using mode as `'a'` (append) and write the headers with empty data outside of these two loops.

Without getting into the details of what you're calculating and writing out, the way to make it *append* data to the outfiles would be:

1. Create the files with just the headers at the start of the script.
2. The last inner loop should write to the files in append mode.

---

So, at the **start** of your script, add:

```
data = json.load(file)
# Create individual empty files with headers
for i in data:
    name = 'Glassdoor_A_' + str(i)
    with open(name+'.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)  # you probably don't need to use the csv module for the first part
        writer.writerow(["Text Main Words", "Text Main Occurrences"])
        # nothing else here for now
```

Then at the **end** of your script, for the inner most loop where you're writing out the data, do:

```
while end_date <= last_end_date:
    ...
    for index, row in filtered_dates.iterrows():
        ...
        for i in data:
            name = 'Glassdoor_A_' + str(i)
            with open(name+'.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:  # note the 'append' mode
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerows([occurrence])
```

<sub>Btw, that last line `writer.writerows([occurrence])` should probably be `writer.writerows(list(occurrence))` if `occurrence` is not already a list of tuples or a list of lists with two elements in each inner list.</sub>

Comment: Many thanks for the great answer - that's very helpful. Thought the shifts, I am not defining the file name anymore and receive the following output `File name too long: 'Glassdoor_A_{\'No\': \'121\', \'Stock Symbol\': \'A\', \'Date\': \'2017-05-11\', \'Author Job Title\': \'Current Employee - QA Chemist\', \'Author Location\': \'Santa Clara, CA\', \'Text Main\': \'I have been working at Agilent`. Is there any way to include it with the period interval labels used beforehand?

Comment: When you do `for i in data:` each `i` is an entire record. You could shorten the filename and use some useful component of the record in the filename. Such as - `i['No']` for the number or `i['Stock Symbol']`. For example, `name = 'Glassdoor_A_' + i['Stock Symbol']`. You can use period dates too but then your inner loop would get overwritten. As I explained in my answer, I can't make out what you're actually trying to do so can't advise on what the better way is. As for not overwriting your CSVs, steps as per my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I am once again receiving a broad number of files without any content though, so have to check if there are other points I have to change....